# How do I get the index of a specific column in a grouped column (multi header) Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid which has grouped column headers (Two headers) binded with data source.  I am using the following code to get the column index of single header row grid which is working fine.

```
dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var rows = grid.tbody.children();
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(rows[0]);
            var priColIndex = grid.wrapper.find(".k-grid-header [data-field=FromDemandQty]").index();
            var cell = row.children().eq(priColIndex);

            if (dataItem.FromDemandQty < 0)
                cell.addClass('stkShort');
            else  
                cell.addClass('stkExcess');
}
```

But this is not working when my kendo grid has two header rows. Below is the Screen shot of my kendo grid. Above mentioned code returns index as 1 when I actually trying to get the index of excess/short column in the image which looks it is reseting the index when a new group starts (Group name : Requestor Data, refer the image)

[image]

Comment: mmm so I'm trying to understand what you are asking. Are you trying to get the row or the column? Which column is the column you are getting and which is the one you need? Are they grouped at all?

Comment: @Keith, Actually my some of the columns in the kendo grid is grouped (merged with title header). I need to get the index of "Excess/Short" column to set the class for that column based on some condition. Please refer the attached image. When I use the above mentioned code its returning 1 as index but actually the index is 6. So I am seeking help to get the actual index of that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. This will work for both the scenario mentioned on my question

Insteed of taking the index directly, need to take the index of column's dataset

Existing code :

```
var priColIndex = grid.wrapper.find(".k-grid-header [data-field=FromDemandQty]").index();
var cell = row.children().eq(priColIndex);

if (dataItem.FromDemandQty < 0)
    cell.addClass('stkShort');
else  
    cell.addClass('stkExcess');
```

Should be changed as :

```
var fromDemCell = grid.wrapper.find(".k-grid-header [data-field=FromDemandQty]");
if (fromDemCell.length > 0) {
    var priColIndex = parseInt(fromDemCell[0].dataset.index);
    var cell = row.children().eq(priColIndex );
    if (dataItem.FromDemandQty < 0) {
        cell.addClass('stkShort');
    } else {                               
        cell.addClass('stkExcess');
    }
}
```